# Create product using SOAP API and JSON input

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap, json, create-product

I need to create product with `SOAP API` and `JSON`, here is my `JSON` input:

```
  {"sku":"tsett","name":"TEST","weight":"3.0000","qty":"18.0000","brand":"sample","category_ids":["107","108","109"],"pirce":"Rs. 1,500.00","description ":"sample disc"}
```

here is the create product api code, how to add the json request using values of request to create the product:

```
    $client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');
    $session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
    $attributeSets = $client->call($session, 'product_attribute_set.list');
    $attributeSet = current($attributeSets);
  $result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.create', array('simple', $attributeSet['set_id'], 'product_sku', array(
'categories' => array(2),
'websites' => array(1),
'name' => 'Product name',
'description' => 'Product description',
'short_description' => 'Product short description',
'weight' => '10',
'status' => '1',
'url_key' => 'product-url-key',
'url_path' => 'product-url-path',
'visibility' => '4',
'price' => '100',
'tax_class_id' => 1,
'meta_title' => 'Product meta title',
'meta_keyword' => 'Product meta keyword',
'meta_description' => 'Product meta description'
   )));

      var_dump ($result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decode JSON data and assign values as per requirement

```
$myJsonData = '{"sku":"tsett","name":"TEST","weight":"3.0000","qty":"18.0000","brand":"sample","category_ids":["107","108","109"],"pirce":"Rs. 1,500.00","description":"sample disc"}';

$myJsonData= json_decode($myJsonData,1);

$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
$attributeSets = $client->call($session, 'product_attribute_set.list');
$attributeSet = current($attributeSets);

$result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.create', array('simple', $attributeSet['set_id'], $myJsonData['sku'], array(
        'categories' => array_values($myJsonData['category_ids']),
        'websites' => array(1),
        'name' => $myJsonData['name'],
        'description' => $myJsonData['description'],
        'short_description' => 'Product short description',
        'weight' => $myJsonData['weight'],
        'status' => '1',
        'url_key' => 'product-url-key',
        'url_path' => 'product-url-path',
        'visibility' => '4',
        'price' => $myJsonData['pirce'],
        'tax_class_id' => 1,
        'meta_title' => 'Product meta title',
        'meta_keyword' => 'Product meta keyword',
        'meta_description' => 'Product meta description'
)));
var_dump ($result);
```

**UPDATE**

For multiple product as per your request

```
 $myJsonData = '{"products":[{"sku":"tsett","name":"TEST","weight":"3.0000","qty":"18.0000","brand":"sample","category_ids":["107","108","109"],"pirce":"Rs. 1,500.00"},{"sku":"product_sku","name":"Product name","weight":"10.0000","qty":"0.0000","brand":null,"category_ids":["2"],"pirce":"Rs. 100.00"}]}';

 $myJsonData = json_decode($myJsonData,1); 

 foreach($myJsonData['products'] as $_product) {

      $result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.create', array('simple', $attributeSet['set_id'], $_product['sku'], array(
            'categories' => array_values($_product['category_ids']),
            'websites' => array(1),
            'name' => $_product['name'],
            'description' => $_product['description'],
            'short_description' => 'Product short description',
            'weight' => $_product['weight'],
            'status' => '1',
            'url_key' => 'product-url-key',
            'url_path' => 'product-url-path',
            'visibility' => '4',
            'price' => $_product['pirce'],
            'tax_class_id' => 1,
            'meta_title' => 'Product meta title',
            'meta_keyword' => 'Product meta keyword',
            'meta_description' => 'Product meta description'
    )));   
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, if it is multiple product how to change example here is my input {"products":[{"sku":"tsett","name":"TEST","weight":"3.0000","qty":"18.0000","brand":"sample","category_ids":["107","108","109"],"pirce":"Rs. 1,500.00"},{"sku":"product_sku","name":"Product name","weight":"10.0000","qty":"0.0000","brand":null,"category_ids":["2"],"pirce":"Rs. 100.00"}]}

Comment: use foreach loop

Comment: @vellaidurai added update for your new json data